# Ignoring a test class based on Spring Boot profile

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, gradle

Take any Spring Boot project with unit tests and integration tests. I would like to run the unit tests separately, without losing the ability to run all tests at once. A solution to this question:

1. runs both unit tests and integration tests by default from IntelliJ,
2. supports a Gradle command that runs both unit tests and integration tests from the cli, and
3. supports a Gradle command that runs only unit tests from the cli. It is important that the integration test classes are ignored entirely, because they contain external dependencies that are not available in the build environment.

My approach is to pass the test profile on the command line: `gradlew test -PtestProfile=unit`

Next, in `build.gradle`, set the active spring profile:

```
test {
    if (project.hasProperty("testProfile")) {
        systemProperty "spring.profiles.active", project.getProperties()["testProfile"]
    }
}
```

The question: **how do I annotate my integration test class, so that whenever `spring.profiles.active=unit`, the integration tests are skipped?**

I tried:

- `@Profile`, which does not work in test scope,
- `@IfProfile`, which does not work for scenario 1 because it requires an explicit property to be passed.
- `@ActiveProfiles`, which does not work because it overrides the currently active profile rather than conditionally disabling the test.

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: I would filter tests based on the name of their classes, or use categories/tags: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#test_grouping.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you, I would prefer to stick to a solution that works natively in Spring Boot (jUnit 4), so `@Tag` is not available but `excludeCategories` works!

Comment: That seems like a bad solution to me: you want to ignore spring integration tests, but base the decision on something that needs a Spring context to be started to evaluate what the profile is. Isn't it contradictory?

Comment: @JBNizet Well, not entirely. It is a typical Spring Boot pattern to have certain classes enabled/disabled depending on the application environment. It would be nice if jUnit or Spring handled this rather than Gradle, because that would make the tests independent from the build tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @JBNizet, the following solution works for me.

We still pass a test profile on the command line: 
`gradlew test -PtestProfile=unit`

In `build.gradle`, we set an `excludeCategory`:

```
test {
    if (project.hasProperty("testProfile")) {
        if (project.getProperties()["testProfile"] == "unit") {
            useJUnit {
                excludeCategories "com.yourproject.testutils.IntegrationTestCategory"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Add an empty interface `com.yourproject.testutils.IntegrationTestCategory`. On the test class you wish to exclude, add the annotation `@Category(IntegrationTestCategory.class)`.

Your test is now enabled by default but can be optionally ignored via the Gradle cli.